# React Navlink changes url but not page

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks

Ii have react app that also takes parameters from the URL and gets data from Mongoose using it, when having navlink to change the ID of the user, when clicked the URL changes, but the page does not refresh or change.

App.js looks like that:

```js
return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter> {
        isAuth()
      }
        <div>
          <div className="content">
            <Switch>
              <PublicRoute path="/login" component={Login} isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />
              <PrivateRoute path="/:id/whatsapper" component={Whatsapper} isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />
              <PrivateRoute path="/profile" component={ProfilePage} isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />
              <PrivateRoute path="/:id/canned-replies-settings" component={CannedRepliesPage} isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />
              <PublicRoute path="/reset-password" component={ForgotPasswordPage} isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />
              <Redirect to={isAuthenticated ? '/Whatsapper' : '/login'} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter> 
    </div>
); 
}
```

The navlinks look like this:

```html
<ul>
    {
        departments.length > 0 ? departments.map((el, i) => (
          <div className="departmentItem" key={i}>
              <li className="departmentListItems"
                  >
                    <WorkIcon className="suiteCaseIcon"/>
                    <NavLink className="departmentListItemsLink" to={"/"+el._id+"/whatsapper"} >{el.departmentName || ''}</NavLink>
                    </li>
              {/* <hr className="profilePageSentenceListHr" /> */}
          </div>
       )) : <p>not found</p>
     }
</ul>
```

Comment: Ok, seems like the page is refreshing but the data i am taking with axios is not being taken again, how can i resend request for server to get new data for this id param? i am not using componenet but function.

Comment: Use the useEffect hook.
useEffect( () => {
//API call
}, []);

This will call your API once page is load. You will get the params from match.

Answer (score 1):

This problem in react usually happens when a path is not associated with a component (often misspells ) since the path is changed by browser and component changed by react. In this case, this is the culprit `/Whatsapper`

```
      <Redirect to={isAuthenticated ? '/Whatsapper' : '/login'} />
```

PS: please either create a component for `/Whatsapper` path or redirect to `/:id/whatsapper` with associated id or remove `Redirect` entirely.